# How to access a TinyMCE template in python code or TAL?

Tags: templates, plone, plone-5.x

In Plone 5 you can make use of html templates in the TinyMCE editor by registering the template plugin. The templates are html snippets living in the file system which are also registered in the plone ressource registry. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<registry>
  <record name="plone.templates" interface="Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.controlpanel.ITinyMCESchema" field="templates">
    <field type="plone.registry.field.Text">
      <default></default>
      <description xmlns:ns0="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n" ns0:domain="plone" ns0:translate="help_tinymce_templates">
        Enter the list of templates in json format http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:template
      </description>
      <required>False</required>
      <title xmlns:ns0="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n" ns0:domain="plone" ns0:translate="label_tinymce_templates">Templates</title>
    </field>
    <value>[
      {"title": "Template 1", "url": "++theme++mytheme/tinymce-templates/tmpl1.html"},
      {"title": "Template 2", "url": "++theme++mytheme/tinymce-templates/tmpl2.html"}
        ]</value>
  </record>
  <record name="plone.custom_plugins" interface="Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.controlpanel.ITinyMCESchema" field="custom_plugins">
      <field type="plone.registry.field.List">
        <default/>
        <description xmlns:ns0="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n" ns0:domain="plone" ns0:translate="">
          Enter a list of custom plugins which will be loaded in the editor. Format is pluginname|location, one per line.
        </description>
        <required>False</required>
        <title xmlns:ns0="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n" ns0:domain="plone" ns0:translate="">Custom plugins</title>
        <value_type type="plone.registry.field.TextLine"/>
      </field>
      <value>
        <element>template|+plone+static/components/tinymce-builded/js/tinymce/plugins/template</element>
      </value>
  </record>
</registry>
```

My question is: How can the templates be accessed from python code or from TAL? First possibility is to read the file from the filesystem. But then the security layer will be passed by. The second is to request the templates by http. In this case safety is taken into account. But it is rather expensive. Is there a way to access the templates (plone resources) direct without bypassing security?

Comment: You will have better luck getting answers by posting in our forum, community.plone.org, though I posted a link on the forum to your question here

Answer (score 0):

You can access the templates direcly by the url.
Something like:

```
portal.restrictedTraverse('++theme++mytheme/tinymce-templates/tmpl2.html')
```

The same applies to page templates.